# How do you create a make file and minify it for pdf.js?

Tags: 7, files

I want to install the [PDF](http://drupal.org/project/pdf) module. In the modules "Getting Started" instructions, I read the following sentence:

> Make pdf.js file in the pdf.js/build directory by following the README.

The README file includes these instructions:

> In order to bundle all `src/` files into a final `pdf.js`, issue:
>
> ```
> $ make
> ```
>
> This will generate the file `build/pdf.js` that can be included in your final project. (WARNING: That's a large file! Consider minifying it).

How do you accomplish this from a Windows machine?
Does it require the web server to be a linux machine?
Does this require SSH'ing into the remote host?

Answer (score 1):

> How do you accomplish this from a Windows machine?

No, you can't run `make` command in Windows; maybe you want to check [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com).

> Does it require the web server to be a linux machine?

Final .js file can be placed anywhere, Windows or Linux. You need a Linux machine to create it.

> Does this require SSH'ing into the remote host?

If you want run `make command` in your server, you need ssh-ing.